# Pagination Does Not Work In My Blog Page in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, pagination, blogs

Hi everyone I create my own template in wordpress...

I want to show the paginate in the blog page to show only 5 post per page for this I have this.

I Have Try to Add Pagination In My Blog Page But It Doesn't Work

Please See My Code Below. Any Help Would Be Greatly Appreciated:

I have Create A Shortcode For Get All Posts and Try  To Add Pagination But It Doesn't Work

This Is My Functions.php File:

```
function short_code($atts){


    ob_start();

 //$featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(),'full'); 

      extract(shortcode_atts(array(

      'posts' => -1,

        'cat'=>'',

          'show_cat'=>false,

         'order'=>'DESC',

          'post_id'=>''

          

   ), $atts));

   $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

 $args = array(

    'post_type' => 'post',

    'post_status' => 'publish',

    'category_name' => '',

    'posts_per_page' => $posts,

    'orderby'=>$order,

    'paged' => $paged

);          

    if( empty($post_id)) 

    {

        $post = get_post($post_id); //assuming $id has been initialized

        setup_postdata($post);

    }

    

$arr_posts = new WP_Query( $args );

 

if ( $arr_posts->have_posts() ) :

 

    while ( $arr_posts->have_posts() ) :

        $arr_posts->the_post();

        ?>

        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?> >

          <div class="image_cusm">  <?php

            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) :

                the_post_thumbnail();

            endif;

            ?>

            </div>

            <header class="entry-header">

                <h1 class="entry-title" ><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

            </header>

            <div class="entry-content">

                <span class='cat_cus'><?php the_category(', '); ?> </span>

                <p class="author_clas"><i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i> <?php the_author();  ?></p>

                <p class="meta_date"> <?php the_time( 'd M' ); ?> </p>

                 <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a> 

            </div>

        </article>

        <?php

    endwhile;

    $total_pages = $data->max_num_pages;

    if ($total_pages > 1){

        $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

        echo paginate_links(array(
            'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
            'format' => '/page/%#%',
            'current' => $current_page,
            'total' => $total_pages,
            'prev_text'    => __('« prev'),
            'next_text'    => __('next »'),
        ));
    }

endif;

    

    return ob_get_clean();

  } 

    add_shortcode("show_posts","short_code");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is one big mistake, and few things you can improve.

You do not have pagination because of that:

```
extract(
    shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'posts'    => -1,
            'cat'      => '',
            'show_cat' => false,
            'order'    => 'DESC',
            'post_id'  => '',
        ),
        $atts
    )
);

$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'category_name'  => '',
    'posts_per_page' => $posts,
    'orderby'        => $order,
    'paged'          => $paged,
);
```

your post_per_page is equal to -1 (if you do not put any param to shortcode) and this mean, that you will print all posts. So no pagination. You need to set this default to some number above 0.

This should solve your issue, but there are few things to improve. Extract is not the best function to use, as it is resource consuming. In your case, it can be better to just assing variables:

```
$params = shortcode_atts(
    array(
        'posts'    => -1,
        'cat'      => '',
        'show_cat' => false,
        'order'    => 'DESC',
        'post_id'  => '',
    ),
    $atts
);
$posts = $params['posts'];
```

Next thing is ob_start(); function. It is a buffer to gather things you want to print. So there is no need to keep whole logic inside this buffer. Limit it only to your HTML code:

So it can be placed here:

```
ob_start();
?>

<?php if ( $arr_posts->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $arr_posts->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php $arr_posts->the_post(); ?>
```

Next is this part of code:

```
if ( empty( $post_id ) ) {
    $post = get_post( $post_id ); //assuming $id has been initialized
    setup_postdata( $post );
}
```

You check if $post_id is empty and if YES you use it. So first you check that $post_id is empty, and then you assume that it has been initialized, what is not true. So this if makes no sense.

Lastly I do not recommend to mixing statements like this:

```
<?php
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) :
        the_post_thumbnail();
    endif;
?>
```

It should look like this:

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You keep your code clean and more readable.